# Informatica power center http transformation post method send txt file with multiple response

Tags: http, post, transformation, informatica

I have data in the table using that I need to post the data on swagger by giving the header information get the response code or status into a application through file with informatica power center with HTTP transformation

I am new to API and HTTP transformation

Comment: I need the steps in detail

Comment: Hi! Please review the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page on how to ask a good question.
This site is not www.tutorialspoint.com - if you need step by step tutorials and introductions, try that or google some tutorial videos.